# django-rest-framework login via Ajax returns HTML

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using the django-rest-framework and trying to login using Ajax, but the login API is returning HTML instead of JSON.

My configs:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    )
}
```

And the Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api-auth/login/',
    method: 'POST',
    data: "username=xxxxx&password=123",
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json'
    },
    success: function(resp) {
        console.log(resp);
    },
    error: function(resp) {
        console.error(resp);
    }
});
```

Even if I'm specifying the `Accept` header, it always returns `text/html`.

Am I using the wrong endpoint?

I'm using JSONWebToken for external clients (ie, mobile) and the SessionAuthentication for same domain web requests. I expect the SessionAuthentication to set the cookie I can use to make further requests once logged in.  If the login fails, I expect the API to return the error in JSON (ie, "Invalid username and password").

**urls.py** (important parts)

```
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ...

    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    url(r'^api-token-auth/', obtain_jwt_token),
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

**Using:**
Django==1.11
djangorestframework==3.7.7
djangorestframework-jwt==1.11.0

Comment: can you show the urls file?, did you try with curl?

Comment: @MauricioCortazar added.

Comment: try with the `api-token-auth`, or show the urls in `rest_framewort.urls`

Comment: @MauricioCortazar but that's for the json web token. I want it to set the cookie. I believe it doesn't do that. I'll try your suggestions in a minute.

Comment: can you put the ViewSet Code?

Comment: I don't remember but you just have to set the value `'JWT_AUTH_COOKIE': 'you_cookie_name',` inside the `JWT_AUTH` dictionary and it will return a cookie

Comment: @MauricioCortazar Thanks! Setting `JWT_AUTH = { 'JWT_AUTH_COOKIE': 'auth', }` and pointing to `/api-token-auth/` worked. Want to post it as an answer and I'll accept it? Thanks

Comment: @DiegoJancic added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set a http only cookie you just have to add the parameter `'JWT_AUTH_COOKIE': 'you_cookie_name',` inside the dictionary `JWT_AUTH` in `settings.py` also remember use the view that provide `django_rest_framework_jwt` located in `from rest_framework_jwt.views import obtain_jwt_token` in your case `api-token-auth/'`